Is it possible to share the internet to the device from host using adb reverse?
I have isolated the device from the internet (switched off the wifi and turned off the mobile internet) connected the device to the host machine through usb cable.
And did the adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:80 on the device. From the device I was able to access localhost:8080 is it possible that we can share the internet as well?
like if I search something like this http://localhost:8080/?url=www.reddit.com/ <-- Is this work?

No, internet connection through port forwarding doesn't work this way. Because port forwarding just redirects the TCP stream. Which program should evaluate the URL http://localhost:8080/?url=www.reddit.com/?
Using port forwarding you can only connect to a single host, the host you forward the port to. Also port forwarding makes problems when using https as the host name does not match.
Both prowblems can be bypassed by using an HTTP proxy on the PC, e.g. on port 8080 and forward that port via adb reverse to port 8080 the Android phone.
On Android side you then have to configure 127.0.0.1:8080 as HTTP proxy. I am not sure if a proxy configuration is effective with mobile and Wifi disabled.
Because of the proxy configuration the HTTP client on the phone will first talk to the HTTP proxy on the PC and send it a special HTTP proxy command telling the proxy which site it want to access (HTTP CONNECT). The HTTP proxy then can establish the connection to the target site and redirect the data traffic of that connection until it is closed.
Note that there are certain development frameworks that ignore configured proxy settings and always want to make a direct connection. Those apps won't work.
